# Devise sign_out_and_redirect flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm running a Rails 3.2.14 app with Devise 2.1.2 and am checking for concurrent/duplicate sessions in my application controller.

I'd like to be able to display a flash notice in template view after I call signout_and_redirect in my application controller that displays "Duplicate login detected"

Here's what my code looks like:

**application_controller.rb**

```
def check_concurrent_session
    if duplicate_session?
      flash[:notice] = "Duplicate Login Detected"
      sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
    end
  end

  def duplicate_session?
    user_signed_in? && (current_user.login_token != session[:token])
  end
```

I've tried it with the above code, but when I trigger a duplicate session the browser does sign out but does not display the flash notice.

In my **application.html.erb** I have the following setup to display flash notice/alerts.

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <p class="alert"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:alert] %>
  <p class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use session?

```rb
def check_concurrent_session
  if duplicate_session?
    sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
    session[:duplication_notice] = "Duplicate Login Detected"
  end
end

# users/sessions_controller.rb

def new
  if session[:duplication_notice].present?
    flash.now[:alert] = session[:duplication_notice]
    session.delete(:duplication_notice)
  end
  super
end
```

Lifetime of `flash` is until next action.

1. `sign_out_and_redirect`
2. `authenticate_user!`
3. `sign_in`

log

```console
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-13 17:08:02 +0900
Processing by Users::FunctionsController#home as HTML
Filter chain halted as :check_concurrent_session rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-13 17:08:02 +0900
Processing by Users::FunctionsController#home as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-13 17:08:02 +0900
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 3258ms (Views: 3254.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Because `sign_out` clear the `session`, session set after sign_out.

[Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)

Comment: I'll give this a shot this morning.  Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3):

You can sign out without redirecting and make the redirect with flash message later. Using the [after_sign_out_path_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers%3Aafter_sign_out_path_for) method will ensure that you use the correct path for redirect even if it has been customized.

Following your example:

```
if duplicate_session?
  user = current_user
  sign_out(user)
  redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(user), 
              alert: 'Duplicate Login Detected'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the more recent version of devise, you could also redirect to a new user session path after clearing the user session.

```
if duplicate_session?
  flash[:notice] = "Duplicate Login Detected"
 
  sign_out current_user

  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

This will persist the flash after redirect